# Ловля исключений php 7.1

Tags: php, исключения

Есть класс исключения, унаследованный от **Exception**:

```
<?php
namespace core\exception;

class SessionInitException extends \Exception{

    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

}
```

В некоторых методах происходит "выброс" этого исключения. (Код методов не добавлял, он не важен, просто выбрасывается и все).

Но, при ловле этого **exception'a** в коде - он не обрабатывается, а просто пропускается и прерывается соответственно программа.

```
use core\exception;
use types\UserShoppingData;

$user_shopping_data = UserShoppingData::get_instance();

try {
    echo json_encode($user_shopping_data->jsonSerialize());
} catch (SessionInitException $six) {
    $user_shopping_data->reinit_data();
    echo json_encode($user_shopping_data->jsonSerialize());
}
```

Результатом ловли получается это:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught core\exception\SessionInitException: Session var's 'isUserCorrect' is not set! in F:\OpenServer\domains\talas-shop.order\application\modules\types\UserShoppingData.php:94
Stack trace:
#0 F:\OpenServer\domains\talas-shop.order\application\modules\types\UserShoppingData.php(179): types\UserShoppingData->get_trash_data()
#1 F:\OpenServer\domains\talas-shop.order\application\processing\service\init_template_data.php(11): types\UserShoppingData->refresh_shopping_data()
#2 {main}
  thrown in F:\OpenServer\domains\talas-shop.order\application\modules\types\UserShoppingData.php on line 94
```

Хотя должна быть обработка исключения.

Если ловить не **exception**, а уже **throwable**:

```
try {
    $user_shopping_data->refresh_shopping_data();
    echo json_encode($user_shopping_data->jsonSerialize());
} catch (Throwable $t) {
    echo "IN THROWABLE CATCH STATEMENT\n";
    $user_shopping_data->reinit_data();
    echo json_encode($user_shopping_data->jsonSerialize());
} catch (SessionInitException $six) {
    $user_shopping_data->reinit_data();
    echo json_encode($user_shopping_data->jsonSerialize());
}
```

Обрабатывается как надо:

```
IN THROWABLE CATCH STATEMENT
{"favorite_count":0,"favorite_data":[],"trash_count":0,"trash_data":[],"login_state":false}
```

Реализация метода *jsonSerialize()*:

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return [
        'favorite_count' => $this->favorite_count,
        'favorite_data' => $this->favorite_data,
        'trash_count' => $this->trash_count,
        'trash_data' => $this->trash_data,
        'login_state' => $this->login_state
    ];
}
```

Окей, в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.errors.php7.php) пишут (цитата делает этот текст *не читаемым*):

```
try
{
   // Code that may throw an Exception or Error.
}
catch (Throwable $t)
{
   // Executed only in PHP 7, will not match in PHP 5
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   // Executed only in PHP 5, will not be reached in PHP 7
}
```

А на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/261451/) пишут:

> Пользовательские классы не могут реализовывать Throwable.

Как тогда создавать и отлавливать **свои** исключения?

Comment: у вас с неймспейсами точно путаницы нет? use core\exception; catch (exception\SessionInitException $six). может быть нужно catch (SessionInitException $six) ?

Comment: Реализация интерфейса транзитивна, т.е. наследуясь от Exception вы получаете реализацию Throwable - подразумевается, что вы напрямую никогда его не реализуете. По основному вопросу пока ничего не могу сказать.

Comment: @myxaxa, да, возможно там была ошибка, сделал как должно быть. Вопрос в силе.

Comment: @Ep1demic, Exception реализует Throwable, как и сказал Etki. а 2й вызов echo json_encode($user_shopping_data->jsonSerialize()); точно не кидает исключение по-новой?:)

Comment: @myxaxa, точно, он обращается к полям, добавил в описание вопроса.

Comment: @Etki, мне, как начинающему, страшновато читать комментарий от пользователя, у которого 45% ответов по php, что он не может ничего сказать по основному вопросу(( Навевает безысходностью и тленностью((

Comment: @Ep1demic, вот простой пример: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa288835d7d2a3bf941fe27f0d6986baf72e7e6e - все ок. ловит, где нужно. попробуйте у себя в блоке try просто кинуть свой эксепшн.

Comment: @Ep1demic, и, судя по бэктрейсу, у вас что-то ещё делается же в types\UserShoppingData->jsonSerialize(). ведь эксепшн летит оттуда, если ничего не путаю:)

Comment: @Ep1demic, я больше двух лет уже практически не пишу на PHP. На первый взгляд все выглядит ок, и, возможно, вы выцепили баг PHP.  Попробуйте отловить исключение по абсолютному FQCN.

Comment: Наоборот, это хороший знак. Значит дело не в бобине. Пиши минимально воспроизводимый тест, и убеждайся, что все работает. После этого ищи опечатки в своем коде. Вопросы состоящие из огрызков кода в стиле "тут играть, тут не играть, тут селедку заворачивали" смысла не имеют

Comment: @myxaxa, да, в той песочнице он действительно ловит, в моем коде - нет.

Comment: Надо послушаться доброго совета и сделать *воспроизводимый* пример. Гадать, почему ваш код у вас не работает - занятие малоэффективное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемы в неймспейсах:

Во первых, `Exception` и `\Exception` - 2 разных класса,
первый - это `core\exception\Exception`

Во вторых, `use core\exception;` недостаточно для импорта исключений.

Возможно:
 Указать класс полностью:

```
try {} catch (core\exception\SessionInitException $six) {}
```

Импортировать класс полностью:

```
use core\exception\SessionInitException;
try {} catch (SessionInitException $six) {}
```

Импортировать из пространства имён:

```
use core\exception;
try {} catch (exception\SessionInitException $six) {}
```

Импортировать с помощью алиаса:

```
use core\exception as ex;
try {} catch (ex\SessionInitException $six) {}
```

[Поведение в разных версиях](https://3v4l.org/KXISC) идентично, за исключением возможности ловить `Throwable` в `php<7`

Answer (score 0):

Лови исключение как \Exception и смотри, что у тебя там

```
    try {
        // do something
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        exit(get_class($e));
    }
```